# jsch - send special keys (CTRL-C, CTRL-D, etc.)

Tags: java, jsch

I need to send special keys to a remote terminal, how can I do that with JSCH?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to sshj and use the signal enumeration to send signals, if needed.

Walter

Answer (score 1):

Try sending two bytes: 0x03, 0x04.

Check [ASCII table](http://www.bbdsoft.com/ascii.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks, I actually switched to another library, sshj.  It manages signals a little bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a signal like this:

```
channel.sendSignal("2"); // sends (CTRL+C) signal
```