# Jsch: Is there way to send Control Character

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using Jsch to connect sshd server and I am new in this area. I successfully send non-control character such as, a, b ...so-on. However, I need to send "Esc" key command (Control Character) to perform specific task. According to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366923/sending-sigint-ctrl-c-using-ganymed-ssh2), I tried several ways (by passing "27", "0033", "0x1b", and "^[") but did not work. 
I have found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167818/jsch-send-special-keys-ctrl-c-ctrl-d-etc) to use sshj. Is there way to send Control Character using Jsch?

Thanks M.F.H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. I have figured out this issue a little different way. I am sending character to VT100 terminal using JSCH to perform specific tasks. In the code, all inputs are converted to array of byte but the ASCII control character cannot be sent as a array of byte to VT100 terminal. According to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366923/sending-sigint-ctrl-c-using-ganymed-ssh2), I have to send control character as ASCII code (INT). Such as, If VT100 terminal needs ESC command then 27 (INT) must be written in the SSH Session input stream. ESC's ASCII code is 27. (Before, I sent 27 as string and converted to array of byte.)

Answer (score 2):

How about following snippet?

```
byte[] esc = { (byte)0x1b }; 
out.write(esc);
out.flush();
```

JCTerm, which is using JSch, has following [definitions](https://github.com/ymnk/jcterm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jcraft/jcterm/EmulatorVT100.java#L554-569),

```
byte[] ENTER = {(byte)0x0d};
byte[] UP = {(byte)0x1b, (byte)0x4f, (byte)0x41};
byte[] DOWN = {(byte)0x1b, (byte)0x4f, (byte)0x42};
byte[] RIGHT = {(byte)0x1b, (byte)0x4f, (byte)0x43};
byte[] LEFT = {(byte)0x1b, (byte)0x4f, (byte)0x44};
....
```

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out this issue. I am sending character to VT100 terminal using JSCH. In the code, all inputs are converted to array of byte.  ANSI/VT100 Terminal accepts only PLAIN ASCII character code (INT) for command/control character. Therefore, the 
control ASCII character cannot be sent as a array of byte.
For example, ESC's ASCII code is 27. If VT100 terminal needs ESC command then 27 (INT) must be written in the SSH Session input stream.